# yii2 active record выбор по условиями из трех таблиц ManyToMany

Tags: yii2, activerecord

1.table product
id
title
status->1

2.table order (промежуточная)
prodict_id
user_id
status 1

3.table user
id
name
email

нужно получить product.title, user.name, user.email
где статусы proudct.status = 1, order.status = 1
sql я написал,

```
SELECT `user`.`username`, `user`.`email`, `product`.`title` 
FROM `user`
 LEFT JOIN `order` ON `order`.`user_id` = `user`.`id` 
 LEFT JOIN `product` ON `order`.`product_id` = `product`.`id` AND `product`.`status` = 1
 WHERE `order`.`status` = 1
```

а как это же сделать в экив рекордс, не могу понять.
возможно удобней указать условия в энтити
типа

```
public function getOrders()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Product::className(), ['id' => 
'product_id'])
        ->viaTable('order', ['user_id' => 'id'])
->where('status' => 1);
//пробовал разные варианты onCondition и т.д.
//вычитал что может лучше укаызвать via, но что-то тоже 
//ничего не поулчается.
}
```

код контроллера

```
$users = User::find()
->joinWith([
'orders'
])->all();
```

[image: таблицы]

Comment: этот код возвращает все записи игнорируя условия(статусы), где и как их прописать не могу понять.

Comment: Вроде так `$users = User::find()->joinWith(['orders'])->andWhere(["orders.status" => 1])->all();`

Comment: не, не работает, выбирает но игнорит статус продукта, то есть там где proudct.status = 0 тоже выгребает, но не должно, как добавить вот (product.status = 1) это условие?

Comment: если я добавлю 
    (andWhere(['product.status' => 1])

то получаю следующую ошибку
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'product.status' in 'where clause'
The SQL being executed was: SELECT `user`.* FROM `user` LEFT JOIN `order` ON `user`.`id` = `order`.`user_id` LEFT JOIN `product` ON `order`.`product_id` = `product`.`id` WHERE (`order`.`status`=1) AND (`product`.`status`=1)

Comment: покажите, как выглядят ваши таблицы user, product, order

Comment: добавил картинку

Comment: судя по всему проблема в операторе `LEFT JOIN ` попробуйте использовать `JOIN`, то есть `$users = User::find()->joinWith(['orders','products'], true, 'JOIN')->andWhere(["orders.status" => 1, 'product.status' => 1])->all();`

Comment: работает, но игнорирует, то есть выгребает order.status = 0 и order.status = 1, а дожно только order.status = 1 выгребать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Судя по комментариям и ошибке, проблема в JOIN, нужно статусы product и order засунуть внутрь этих операторов

Иначе говоря запрос будет выглядеть примерно так

```
$users = User::find()->
         joinWith(['orders' => function (\yii\db\ActiveQuery $query) {
            $query->where(['order.status' => 1]);
         },
         'products' => function (\yii\db\ActiveQuery $query) {
             $query->where(['product.status' => 1]);
         },
         ]])->all();
```

Comment: Спасибо, получилось! Правда чуть по другому сделал, в ентити, где связи добавил метод с "замыканием" или анонимной функцией - как правильно сказать.